# Meaning of the verb "adorare" in a Christian context

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In the Christmas carol 'Adeste Fideles' there is a line 'Venite adoremus.' I'd like to hear an exploration of the meaning of this term. For instance, would it be appropriate to apply this word to anyone not God? From a Christian standpoint I mean. Given that God is One and he would have his worshippers give worship to him alone, would it be appropriate to apply this word to anyone other than God Himself? I guess I am asking if adoremus is the same thing as worship, or does it mean merely something like appreciation, Does it equate to 'adore' in English? We sometimes say we adore things and people other than God in English of course, but when using adore in it's most basic meaning it ought to really only ever apply to God for a real Christian, right? So what about 'adoremus'?

Comment: So your question is: in Christian Latin, is the term _adorō_ ever used for anything other than "worship"?

Answer (score 1):

L&S on *adorare*: In ecclesiastical Latin, of the worship of the true God: *adoravit Israel Deum*, VULG. *Gen*. 47, 31: *Dominum Deum tuum adorabis*, IB. Matt. 4, 10: *Deum adora*, IB. Apoc. 22, 9; so of Christ: v*identes eum adoraverunt*, IB. Matt. 28, 17; *adorent eum omnes angeli Dei*

EDIT: Originally wrote that this comes from LSJ...

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In ecclesiastical Latin, *adoratio* is the outward expression of the reverence owed to the creator (called *latria*, from Greek λατρεία = service, worship), but also of the reverence due to certain outstanding creatures (like the Saints, the Virgin Mary, or Angels; called *dulia* from Greek δουλεία = bondage; or *hyperdulia* in case of the Virgin Mary).

See [Summa Theologica II, II, 84, 1](https://bkv.unifr.ch/de/works/sth/versions/summa-theologiae/divisions/2299) for St. Thomas Aquinas' discussion of *adoratio*, which touches on all these points.

Nevertheless, I believe that there is a strong tendency to reserve the word for expressions of reverence for God only (including His only begotten Son, as in the song). There are instances – some cited by Aquinas – where *adorare* is used in the Bible for persons other than God. There are several such instance, e.g., in [3 Reg. 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=3%20kings%201&version=VULGATE).

See the entry for [Adoration](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01151a.htm) in the Catholic Encyclopedia for a rather thorough, well written and somewhat opinionated explantion of the matter (based on English usage, but (I think) nonetheless relevant.)

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for the suggestions for further research.